# how to partition in ubuntu after installing?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I have installed ubuntu in my system without partitioning, is there any possibility to partition my disk without reinstalling the ubuntu, i mean in existence ubuntu can i do partitions?

I used whole disk for Ubuntu installation.

Comment: You can do, but better use a live CD.
But besides this, you need to extent the /etc/fstab, so maybe it woulb be faster if you reinstall and use the partitioning programm there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Ubuntu as the only OS on your hard drive you can not partition the hard drive while Ubuntu is running because you have to unmount the drive before being able to partition it.. and you can't unmount the drive while the system is running on it.

You would have to boot from your Ubuntu installation medium and choose the 'Try Ubuntu' option. When the system is booted open the dash and type 'gparted' then choose your HDD and partition it